# Subtract same data one by one

Tags: database, ms-access

I have an table `Sell_Detail` having column `Amount` where the data is same

Example:

```
select amount from sell_detail where amount = 1990
1900
```

when I give input it subtract the value from both similar data mean if their are more then 
one record having similar values

Example:

```
1900,1900
```

I input 200, the result will be

```
1700,1700
```

what result i want:

```
1700,1900
```

Else if value are different it work Nicely 
Help Please
Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to change the value of only one row in the database, or how to subtract a value (e.g. 200) from the first value returned by the query?

Comment: yeah i find the result with first row not the second row

Comment: for example I input amount to deduct is 200 the answer will be 1700,1900 what i get now is (1700,1700)